# 2018 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected [from an earlier thread](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/2018-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers.

Due to the submission count, we have selected all provided questions as well as our back up questions for a total of 10 questions.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/7efb8007-a1d7-4743-b8c6-ec0c57857931/view-source).Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

**Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.**

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

---

> 1. Plugin related questions has always been a hot topic. What are your opinions on the matter?
> 2. The website is currently seeing a downward trend in participation. Why do you think that is and do you think it can be reversed?
> 3. Do you have any kind of past moderation experience? When, where, how do you think it can help here?
> 4. How often do you find yourself using WordPress?
> 5. How much time do you spend right now on our site per day and week? Do you know if you can stay so active or become even more active for the next year?
> 6. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 7. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 8. In your opinion, what do moderators do?
> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 14):

> 1. Plugin related questions has always been a hot topic. What are your opinions on the matter?

Questions can cause issues no matter they are plugin-specific or not. There are questions related to the core that are off-topic, while there are questions regarding a third party plugin that are perfectly on-topic. This matter can't be fully resolved, we just have to take actions about the questions individually.

> 2. The website is currently seeing a downward trend in participation. Why do you think that is and do you think it can be reversed?

This is a tough question. It could be due to participant being busy with their own business, or some others hitting a specific rep amount and then being inactive. I myself spend as much time as I can on here, since WordPress is what I'm actively following and I dig a lot of new information both from answers and questions here.

> 3. Do you have any kind of past moderation experience? When, where, how do you think it can help here?

I do. Although they are not as fancy as SE, but still I've been into moderation since 2008. I've been moderator of several chat rooms ( Which I think is more tense since you have to take action immediately ) and 2 other forums, one regarding mobile phones, the other about Joomla!.

The way this could help is that now I'm aware about most of to come, especially when it gets tense, and when different mods have different opinions.

> 4. How often do you find yourself using WordPress?

I make a living using WordPress. I was into other CMS before ( Joomla!, PrestaShop, etc ) but after i was introduced to WordPress, I'm actively improving my WordPress skills, trying to unleash its inner power.

> 5. How much time do you spend right now on our site per day and week? Do you know if you can stay so active or become even more active for the next year?

As I mentioned in my nomination, I spend almost all of my daily time online, and I have an open tab of WPSE most of the time. I check here approximately about once every 20 minutes or so. This will enable me to act quickly, without having a pile of issues stacked.

> 6. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

As it's almost clear, such a user is probably a professional. This makes it easier to inform them about the situation. What I would do is to first inform the user in a friendly way ( comments, chats ), and if not successful, message the user directly. If this didn't work out either, I'll discuss with the other mods in a chatroom, and see what do the majority of us decide.

> 7. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

The mods here are experienced users. If I don't have much evidence regarding reopening a question, I'll then respect their decision. If I do, then we do have a chatroom for such circumstances :) Luckily most of the mods here gather in the Loop chatroom, and they are acquainted with each other, so this will probably be quickly resolved.

> 8. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Some may have forgotten the meaning of the word [Moderator](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/moderator). Mods are here to help users and the community improve. They are not bosses with sticks, they are those who took responsibility to help the community grow, and help the new users progress.

I myself am more into salvaging posts rather than closing or deleting a post. If there's any chance to improve, or to make an off-topic question on-topic, I'll do it. This means I'll be just a user, unless duty calls.

> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

Fine. I try avoiding conflicts in either answers or comments. Welcoming new users is also what I do a lot. So yes, it probably feels nice to know that these came from a mod, allowing the users to know that mods are also users.

> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

I'm almost 10k myself, but I don't think this will be equal as being a mod. Being able to take action immediately, messaging users when necessary, tracking users activity and so on allows me to resolve an issue more quickly, and more importantly, gives me the responsibility.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

> Plugin related questions has always been a hot topic. What are your
>   opinions on the matter?

Making third-party plugin questions on-topic or off-topic has been the center of debate ever since this platform made its first Sunday roast.

My aim as a moderator would be to allow the community to be a part of the decision making. If it is a controversial decision like this, and one that will quite drastically affected the content of the platform, the decision should be in the hands of the members of the community.

In this scenario, rather than using my power as a moderator to make a decision, I would provoke and campaign (if you wish) to encourage the community (and the upper-tier users/staff of StackExchange) to engage in the decision making itself.

That would be my main purpose.

> The website is currently seeing a downward trend in participation. Why
>   do you think that is and do you think it can be reversed?

I would work towards encouraging users, particularly new ones, to engage in the community. Lack of traffic, or boost of traffic do not necessary affect user participation, but a welcoming community where you can discuss work *and* procrastinate certainly do.

Beyond all of my *online* moderation roles, my partner and I are also moderators, organisers, and hosts of a variety of (in real life) pro and casual networking groups in Stockholm with thousands of members. My experience of connecting people via these groups has been surprisingly handy when working on boosting activity on platforms I moderate online.

> Do you have any kind of past moderation experience? When, where, how
>   do you think it can help here?

Moderation has been a passion of mine ever since I delved into it sometime late 90’s moderating a high trafficked WWWBoard.

Then I moved on to moderate phpBB forums with user bases in the thousands.

Nowadays, I work as a moderator on a variety of platforms, including a leading long-form writing platform with an audience of millions. They all share the same source of existence, and that is *WordPress*.

I have experience of moderation from all corners of the web, and I believe this diverse insight will come in handy for WPSE. Most noticeably, some of the platforms I have worked with have a *rather niche audience* where conflicts easily form and the actions of the mod team are continuously on topic.

> How often do you find yourself using WordPress?

Every single day. I work as a WordPress contractor full time, and on my spare time, I run several established platforms powered by WordPress. So the question should be rephrased to how often I *don't* use WordPress. ;-)

> How much time do you spend right now on our site per day and week? Do
>   you know if you can stay so active or become even more active for the
>   next year?

I spend *at least* 30 minutes on the site on a daily basis, primarily doing [editorial tasks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/24875/christine-cooper?tab=activity&sort=reviews) rather than posting Q&A's. This is actually a very good question that I am hoping to sum up with an answer that makes sense to people who have concerns about activeness.

Being active here is a part of my professional *and* personal routine. Meaning, I work full time, I socialise, run meetup groups, do sports, keep active, *and* engage with WPSE daily.

It can be "easy" to hangout here when you are on a leave, or not active outside of the community, but being here frequently when working towards an active career and social life is whole new butter and bread.

That should highlight where my priorities are. I think some of you who have been a part of this community for a long time will relate, understand, and appreciate this.

> How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of
>   valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of
>   arguments/flags from comments?

I would overview the flagged entries properly (and not skim through them), discuss internally with my fellow moderators, and finally approach the user and engage in a constructive session with the user about the etiquette of the platform.

While the quality of answers are of high value, **the community is the heart of this platform** and should certainly be treated as such.

> How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc
>   a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

This is definitely an internal issue and not one that should be resolved in a public manner. I would discuss the issue with the said moderator and come down to a solution together in how to proceed. If there is still a conflict, I would bring it up with the whole team of moderators and delve into it with a collaborative approach.

> In your opinion, what do moderators do?

As I outlined in my [pitch](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/5#post-295320), my model of moderation is divided into three major processes:

- **Communication**: Understand the lingo to connect with the community and master the art of maintaining a positive approach to resolve conflicts.
- **Collaboration**: Engage with fellow upper-tier users/mods and work together to resolve issues and provoke change when encouraged by the community.
- **Responsibility**: Protect the integrity of the community, understand my rights, and never misuse my power.

You can also read [my tale of moderation](https://medium.com/@c_cooper/a-tale-of-moderation-d8c74e50c831).

> A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the
>   past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will
>   do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

I am completely comfortable with it. I have moderated a variety of high trafficked platforms and learned from it, particularly on how to engage with the community and not to overstep my boundaries.

> In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more
>   effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Reputation doesn't mean anything for me beyond achieving new abilities to perform editorial tasks, which I've found valuable. I've spent my points on more bounties than I can count.

Being a moderator, as opposed to a high rep user, will mean that I will gain the status to do more *upper-tier* moderation tasks. And more importantly, I will have the possibility to provoke change and improvements to the platform. This is something that tends to require a strong voice to kick off and I can be a part of the movement with the assistance of my fellow moderators.

Our aim should be growth in quality contributions in all areas and encourage controversial changes when needed be.

If all fails, I will do a mind-meld with the community members. One by one...

[image: Mind Meld]