# 2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

WordPress Development is scheduled for an election [next week, April 1st](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/6). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

As we did [last time](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/2018-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), we're hosting the question collection a week in advance, so that not only can folks start prepping questions in advance, but also potential candidates can think about nominating themselves and seeing the questions they'll have an opening to answer.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4567/2019-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, April 1st at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: April 1st  are you sure about that?

Comment: And February 26th? 

Answer (score 9):

One major problem we currently have is the lack of regulars. Do you think the moderator team can change that? And if so: how?

Related to that is our very low answer rate: it's only 71% now, and with that we are at the [bottom of all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered). What could be done to improve this situation?

Comment: Oh yeah these ones are really good. As coming from Drupal Answers I'm really surprised on the huge amount of low quality questions on WordPress development and I'm even more surprised that these question receive actual answers.

Comment: @leymannx they receive answers, because people want to get points - so there always will be someone that will post an answer. The real problem, IMHO, is that these questions aren't getting removed/closed fast enough. This also makes it hard to find a valuable questions that really need answers.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Have to have points so you can actually help close tickets, so hence answering any question that will give me points. Haha.

Answer (score 6):

Do you think this community is a welcoming one? Why or why not?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 5):

How much time can you spend on the site for moderator activities per day and week? It should be at least 15-20 minutes, preferably a bit more and not bundled in a single session, meaning we might need you in the mod chat or on flag handling maybe twice per day.